# IPv6 forwarding doesn't work in a network namespace

Tags: networking, ipv6, namespace, forwarding, network-namespaces

I have 3 Linux VMs connected like this:

```
 /       server1         \
| ens19 2001:1::2         |
 \                       /
            |  
 /                       \
| ens19 2001:1::1         |
|        server2          |
| ens20 2001:2::1         |
 \                       /
            |
 /                       \
| ens19 2001:2::2        |
 \       server3         /
```

I run these commands on server1:

```
ip link set dev ens19 up
ip -6 address add 2001:1::2/96 dev ens19
ip -6 route add default via 2001:1::1
```

then these on server3:

```
ip link set dev ens19 up
ip -6 address add 2001:2::2/96 dev ens19
ip -6 route add default via 2001:2::1
```

then these on server2:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
ip link set dev ens19 up
ip link set dev ens20 up
ip -6 address add 2001:1::1/96 dev ens19
ip -6 address add 2001:2::1/96 dev ens20
```

If I try to ping server3 from server1, it works:

```
root@server1:~# ping6 2001:2::2
```

but if I move the interfaces on server2 inside a network namespace:

```
ip netns add net1
ip link set dev ens19 netns net1
ip link set dev ens20 netns net1
ip netns exec net1 ip link set dev ens19 up
ip netns exec net1 ip link set dev ens20 up
ip netns exec net1 ip -6 address add 2001:1::1/96 dev ens19
ip netns exec net1 ip -6 address add 2001:2::1/96 dev ens20
```

ping from server1 to server3 no longer works. Packets are no longer forwarded.

Why? (note: same process for IPv4 works)

Comment: I really would not make IPv6 networks smaller that /64. There are enough addresses to go around without reducing it to /96. And looking at the adresses given, it's not required. The /64 subnet is regarded as being natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps that were done initially but weren't done *again* in the new network namespace:

> ```
> echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
> echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
> ```

It happens the behavior resulting from this is different between IPv4 and IPv6, as documented in the relatively new network toggle that allows to alter this default behavior: [`devconf_inherit_init_net`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/sysctl/net.rst?h=v5.8#n332):

> [...]
> By default, we keep the **current behavior:** for IPv4 we inherit all
> current settings from init_net and **for IPv6 we reset all settings to
> default.**

So in the new network namespace:

- IPv4 forwarding is inherited from initial network namespace. As it was just enabled with `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` run in the initial network namespace, the new network namespace is also set as an IPv4 router.

  So it works fine for IPv4.
- IPv6 is reset to the [default of host](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.15#n2148) rather than router whatever was done in the initial network namespace (unless if for example this is run *before* creating the new network namespace: `sysctl -w net.core.devconf_inherit_init_net=1`)

Just add the missing step, to be run within the new network namespace (`/proc/sys/net/` is network-namespace aware). Using a stdout redirection won't work correctly without some gymnastic, so better use the dedicated command: `sysctl`.

```
ip netns exec net1 sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```